# How to prove that $K[X,Y]$ is a $K$-algebra generated by $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm somewhat confused with the notion of a $K$-algebra.

I know that that $K[X]$ has to be a vector space over $K$. 
This seems to be fine.

I don't know how to prove that $X$ and $Y$ generate $K[X,Y]$ as $K$-algebra.
What would the bilinear law be in this case?

Comment: May be  a boring but formal way is to actually define a polynomial ring over, say a field $K$ as follows. Let $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and define $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ to be the set of all maps $f:\mathbb{N}^n\to K$ such that $f(a_1,\ldots, a_n)=0$ if $\sum a_i>>0$. Define addition on this set by $(f+g)(a_i)=f(a_i)+g(a_i)$ and multiplication by $f(g)(a_i)=\sum f(b_i)g(c_j)$ where the sum is over all tuples with $(b_i)+(c_i)=(a_i)$. Now everything can be checked and define $x_i:\mathbb{N}\to K$ be the map which takes $x_i(a_j)=1$ if $a_i=1$ rest zero and zero for all others.

Answer (score 1):

$K[X,Y]$ certainly is a $K$-algebra. And as soon as a subalgebra contains $1$ and $X$ and $Y$, it contains all polynomial expressions in those, that is all of $K[X,Y]$. To make this more formal, you might perform induction on the (combined) degree of polynomials.

Comment: I used the following definition in order to prove that K[X,Y] is a K-algebra:
[link ]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Definition
However I can't see how to prove the second part of your answer

Comment: The binary law is multiplication of polynomials

Comment: So basically with the additional law I can perform operations like $X*X=X^2$ which shows that all powers of X are in K[X,Y] seen as K-algebra? As the same holds for Y it is then generated by X and Y?